# Image Processing Median Filtering Example

Tags: c, image-processing

I'm working on a median filtering example(image processing) where the filter itself should be a function. I have done everything I could do debug it but, in the 32th and 39th rows the nested loop does not work. I tried to print some basic stuff inside the nested loop but nothing happened. I don't know if the pointer arrays I declared caused this problem, but please can anyone help?All I get at the output is the same gray level value for every pixel.
"som": Size of the mask.
"noi": Number of iterations(How many times should this filter applied?).

**Edited Function:**

```
   unsigned char sort_masking(unsigned char **img_mask,int som, int rn, int cn){
    
    int i,j;
    int temp;
    unsigned char *mask_out;
    mask_out = (unsigned char*)malloc((som*som)*sizeof(unsigned char));
    
    for(i=0;i<som;i++){
        for(j=0;j<som;j++){
            mask_out[i*som+j] = img_mask[rn+i][cn+i];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<(som*som);i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<(som*som);j++){
            if(mask_out[j]<mask_out[i]){
                temp = mask_out[i];
                mask_out[i] = mask_out[j];
                mask_out[j] = temp;             
            }
        }
    }
    return(mask_out[(som*som-1)/2]);
}

unsigned char **median(unsigned char **img, int som, int noi,int NC, int NR){
    
    int i,j;
    unsigned char **img_out;
    img_out = alloc_img(NC,NR);
    
    for(i=0;i<NR;i++){
        for(j=0;j<NC;j++){
            img_out[i][j] = img[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<(NR-som+1);i++){
        for(j=0;j<(NC-som+1);j++){
            img_out[i+(som-1)/2][j+(som-1)/2] = sort_masking(img,som,i,j);
        }
    }
    
    return(img_out);    
}



 unsigned char **alloc_img(int ncol,int nrow){
    int i;
    unsigned char **img;
    
    img = (unsigned char **) malloc((size_t)((nrow+1)*sizeof(unsigned char*)));
    if (!img)
    {
      printf("\n\n Cannot allocate memory (1)\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    
    img[0] = (unsigned char *) malloc((size_t)((nrow*ncol+1)*sizeof(unsigned char)));
    if (!img[0])
    {
      printf("\nCannot allocate memory (2)\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    
    
    for(i=1;i<=nrow;i++)
        img[i]=img[i-1] + ncol;
    
    return (img);
    }
```

Main Function:
int main(int argc, char **argv)

```
{
unsigned char **img, **img2;
char *pgm_file;
int NR,NC,som,noi;

/*---------->>> Start assigning valiables from command line arguments   */
if(argc!=4) {
  printf("\n Usage: median-app [size of the mask] [number of iterations] [Image file (*.pgm)] \n");
  printf("\n E.g.   median-app 7 2 cathedral.pgm \n");
  exit(-1); }
  
som=atoi(argv[1]);                /*  Size of the median filter mask*/
if(som=!3 && som!=5 && som!=7) {printf("\n [size of the mask] should be 3, 5 or 7\n"); exit(0);} 

noi=atoi(argv[2]);
if(noi<1 || noi>10) {printf("\n [number of iterations] should be an integer between 1 and 10\n"); exit(0);} 

pgm_file=argv[3];
/*----------<<< End assigning valiables from command line arguments  */

/*---------->>> Start image manipulation example */
img=pgm_file_to_img(pgm_file,&NC,&NR);/*  read img and its size from file */
show_pgm_file(pgm_file);

img2 = alloc_img(NC,NR);

img2 = median(img,som,noi,NC,NR);
    
img_to_pgm_file(img2,"Median.pgm",NC,NR);
show_pgm_file("Median.pgm");
/*----------<<< End image manipulation example */

free_img(img);
free(img2);
/*  if img is not needed anoymore we can free the allocated memory */

return(1);
}
```

Comment: How do you call your function? I think you could start by simplifying your code a bit, have it do only one iteration for example. Use the debugger to see how the flow through your program actually is.

Comment: `(nrow*ncol+1)` -> `((nrow+1)*ncol)` in `alloc_img()` ?

Comment: `int i,j,k,l,a,b,x,y,z,m,n,temp_1,d,e;` any function that needs 14 nameless variables is off to a bad start. Is that 5 levels of nested loops I see? Your function is trying to do too much. Try to think of ways to modularize and separate functionality. A function should do one thing and do it well.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I tried to modify it as much as possbile(not sure it is enough) but still I'm missing something. In the 'sort_masking()' function loops do not iterate or even start. Function treats them as they are not there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I added the main function above.

Comment: Aside: wouldn't it be way faster to obtain the median via QuickSelect?

Comment: Another aside: you have way more `malloc` calls than `free` calls. You need to pair each `malloc` with a `free`, otherwise you leak memory.

Comment: `img_mask[rn+i][cn+i];` -- you probably meant one of those `i` to be a `j`.